# What is the relationship between VAE and EM algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, inference, expectation-maximization, variational-bayes

I know that the EM algorithm is used in latent variable models, specifically to do maximum likelihood estimation iteratively. Similarly, the VAE can be used for latent variable models and, although they are usually used for generative modeling or posterior inference, they can also be used for parameter inference. So I was wondering what's the relationship between them and when it's better to use one or the other.

Comment: Conceptually, $E\, step$ is to compute the parameters of latent space, which is a pooling effect of data points. Take GMM for example, this is to find out the Categorical distribution for the current iteration, which is equivalent to update $Encoder$ of VAE. At $M\, step$, we find a new $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to maximize the likelihood for GMM by Lagrange method. Again, the counterpart in VAE is minimize the reconstruction error of $Decoder$ by back-propagation. In general, VAE can be viewed as an EM procedure, but more powerful with neural network to handle continuous latent space.

Answer (score 13):

> What is the relationship between VAE and EM?

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\vx}{\vect{x}}
\newcommand{\vz}{\vect{z}}
\newcommand{\vtheta}{\vect{\theta}}
\newcommand{\Ebb}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\vphi}{\vect{\phi}}
\newcommand{L}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\elbo}{L_{\vtheta, \vphi}(\vx)}
\newcommand{\felbo}{L_{\vx}(\vtheta, q_{\vphi})}$

This answer is partially complete, but I've actually written a [blog post](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/post/variational-auto-encoders-and-the-expectation-maximization-algorithm/) about this that goes into the nitty-gritty details!

## Notation

Observed data: $\mathcal{D} = \{\vx_1, \vx_2, \ldots, \vx_N\}$

Latent variables denoted by $\vz$.

## Expectation Maximization Algorithm (Standard Version)

The EM algorithm is often (see for example Wikipedia) described as follows.

Start with a guess $\vtheta^{(0)}$, then until convergence:

- Compute expectations $\Ebb_{p(\vz \mid \vx, \vtheta^{(t)})}[\log p_{\vtheta}(\vx, \vz)]$ for every data point $\vx\in \mathcal{D}$.
- Choose parameter value $\vtheta^{(t+1)}$ to maximize expectations
  $$
  \vtheta^{(t+1)} = \arg\max_{\vtheta} \sum_{\vx\in\mathcal{D}}\Ebb_{p(\vz \mid \vx, \vtheta^{(t)})}[\log p_{\vtheta}(\vx, \vz)] 
  $$

## Expectation-Maximization Algorithm (Rewritten)

One can rewrite the algorithm above in a slightly different way. Rather than computing expectations in the first step, we compute the distributions $p(\vz\mid, \vx, \vtheta^{(t)})$. The EM algorithm then looks as follows:

Start with a guess $\vtheta^{(0)}$, until convergence:

- Compute distributions $\left\{p(\vz\mid, \vx, \vtheta^{(t)}) \, : \, \vx \in \mathcal{D}\right\}$
- Choosen new parameter value in the same way as before
  $$
  \vtheta^{(t+1)} = \arg\max_{\vtheta} \sum_{\vx\in\mathcal{D}}\Ebb_{p(\vz \mid \vx, \vtheta^{(t)})}[\log p_{\vtheta}(\vx, \vz)] 
  $$

## Variational Autoencoders

Why did I rewrite it like that? Because one can write the ELBO, which is usually considered as a function of $\vx$ parametrized by $\vtheta$ and $\vphi$ ($\vphi$ are the parameters of the encoder $q_{\vphi}$), as a functional of $q_{\vphi}$ and a function of $\vtheta$ that is parameterized by $\vx$ (indeed the data is fixed). This means the ELBO can be written as:

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}, q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}})=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \log p_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}})- \text{KL}(q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}}\,\,||\,\,p_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{z}}\mid \boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}})) \qquad \qquad &(1)\\
\qquad \\
\displaystyle \mathbb{E}_{q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}}}[\log p_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathbf{z}})] - \mathbb{E}_{q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}}}[\log q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}}] \qquad \qquad &(2)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Now we can find two identical steps as those of the EM algorithm by performing maximization of the ELBO with respect to $q_{\vphi}$ first, and then with respect to $\vtheta$

- **E-step**: Maximize $(1)$ with respect to $q_{\vphi}$ (this makes the KL-divergence zero and the bound is tight)
  $$
  \left\{p_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}^{(t)}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{z}}\mid \boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}})= \arg\max_{q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}}} \mathcal{L}_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}^{(t)}, q_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\phi}}})\,\, : \,\, \boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}\in\mathcal{D}\right\}
  $$
- **M-step**: Maximize $(2)$ with respect to $\vtheta$
  $$
  \boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}^{(t+1)} = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}} \sum_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}\in\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{L}_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}, p_{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{\theta}}^{(t)}}(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{z}}\mid \boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}))
  $$

The relationship between the Expectation Maximization algorithm and Variational Auto-Encoders can therefore be summarized as follows:

- EM algorithm and VAE optimize the **same objective function**.
- When expectations are in closed-form, one should use the EM algorithm which uses **coordinate ascent**.
- When expectations are intractable, VAE uses **stochastic gradient ascent** on an unbiased estimator of the objective function.

Comment: This seems like a good answer but there are multiple things which remain unclear. 1. What is the difference between the standard and the rewritten EM algorithm, both require us to compute the distribution p(z|x, theta) 2. What is the objective function for the VAE [(1) or (2)]? 3. What does "expectations are in closed-form" even mean?

Comment: @CausalQuestions On question 2. They are equivalent as [ELBO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_lower_bound#Main_forms). We can say one goal of VAE is to push $q_{\phi}$ and $p_{\theta}(\textrm{z}|\textrm{x})$ approaching each other asymptotically, and the part of $\theta$ of $p$ space which deal with Encoder are fixed after E-step. And another goal is to educate the Decoder to generate samples as real as possible, which is M-step. This is just for naive comparison purpose. In reality, they are optimized concurrently by back-propagation.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, both EM and VAE are machine learning techniques/algorithms to find the latent variables **z**. However, despite the overall goal and even the **objective function** being the same, there are differences because of the complexities of the model.

There are 2 issues at hand where EM (and its variants) have limitations. These are mentioned in the original VAE paper, [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114)
by Kingma & Welling.

From section 2.1 of the paper:

> Very importantly, we *do not* make the common simplifying assumptions about the marginal or posterior probabilities. Conversely, we are here interested in a general algorithm that even works efficiently in the case of:
>
> 1. *Intractability*: the case where the integral of the marginal likelihood $p_\theta(x) = \int p_\theta(z) p_\theta(x|z) ,dz$ is intractable (so we cannot evaluate or differentiate the marginal likelihood), where the true posterior density $p_\theta(z|x) = p_\theta(x|z)p_\theta(z)/p_\theta(x)$ is intractable (so the EM algorithm cannot be used), and where the required integrals for any reasonable mean-field VB algorithm are also intractable. These intractabilities are quite common and appear in cases of moderately complicated likelihood functions $p_\theta(x|z)$, e.g. a neural network with a nonlinear hidden layer.
> 2. *A large dataset*: we have so much data that batch optimization is too costly; we would like to make parameter updates using small minibatches or even single datapoints. Sampling-based solutions, e.g. Monte Carlo EM, would in general be too slow, since it involves a typically expensive sampling loop per datapoint.