# Understanding Variational inference and EM in relation to each other

Tags: autoencoders, expectation-maximization, variational-bayes, variational-inference, variational

I have read several answers like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479612/what-is-the-relationship-between-vae-and-em-algorithm) but, somehow I still have a few doubts. I hope to present my understanding and ask a few questions to clear my doubts

EM:

1. A maximization maximization algorithm
2. E-step - Find the distribution that takes the ELBO as close to the likelihood as possible (A maximization). This turns out to be the posterior. **This will be contrasted against variational inference where we are trying to approximate the posterior. In fact, I would claim that this is the motivation for variational inference. This inability to compute posterior analytically. Otherwise, we wouldn't need variational inference**
3. M-step - Maximize the ELBO in the parameter space of assumed $P(X|Z)$ (Also a maximization)

Points to notice:

1. The $P(X)$ here is changing since we are optimizing in the parameter space of the $P(X|Z)$. **This will be contrasted against variation inference where the $P(X)$ is not changing**

Variational Inference:

1. In EM we make simplifying modelling assumptions that allow for the $P(X)$ to be computed and thus $P(Z|X)$ to be computed using the Bayes theorem. Simplifying assumptions like there are 10 normal distributions that the data is generated from (GMM). If we dont make these simplifying assumptions then the denominator in the bayes theorem is not computation feasible and hence we cannot compute the posterior. Now this posterior is to be approximated using variational inference.
2. **(Question 1)** : Am I right in claiming that the **Variational inference is needed in more complex scenarios whereas the EM is applied to simple models like GMM. In fact the two algorithms can be complimentary with variational inference making it possible to apply EM to more complex scenarios where we use the variational inference in the E step to approximate the posterior and then apply the M-step**
3. Am I right in understanding that the likelihood is assumed constant in the variational inference whereas it is changing in the EM?